# Dynamic Linq using SqlFunction Checksum

Tags: c#, linq

I have this function which calculate an checksumAggregate on a set of rows that should themselves be checksum-med.  Unfortunately if the tables don't have a unique INT column so the checksumAggregate isn't enough. I have to use Checksum to be able to use other columns.

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic to allow the function to be generic.

Where the code below references x.ColumnName.ToString() is what I need to replace with something like "ColumnName" like I do for the OrderBy and Where clause. (I would pass the string in another parameter of the function)

Since it uses SQLFunctions I am now stuck at how to do this.  It's a shame there is no "*" for this function.

I really hope this makes sense.  Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

```
    public int calculateChecksum<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string SortColumn, DateTime? TimeStamp, Int64 Offset = 0)
    {
        if (TimeStamp == null) {TimeStamp = new DateTime(1800,1,1);}
        string filterExp = SortColumn + " = @0";
        query = query.Where<T>(filterExp, TimeStamp);
        query = query.OrderBy<T>(SortColumn);
        query = query.Take(varTakeCount);
        int outChecksum = SqlFunctions.ChecksumAggregate(query.Select(x => SqlFunctions.Checksum( x.ColumnName.ToString() )));
        return outChecksum;
    }
```

EDIT:

With a few tweaks I am able to get the ChecksumAggregate to work on a single INT column. Close, but not ideal.

```
        string filterType = typeof(T).FullName.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), filterType);        
        var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, "tablename.columnname");
        int outChecksum = SqlFunctions.ChecksumAggregate(query.Select((Expression<Func<T, int>>)e));
```

Also I tried fooling around with stuff like this:

```
        var checksumMethod = typeof (SqlFunctions).GetMethod("Checksum", new[] {typeof (string), typeof (string)});
        var checksumExpression = Expression.Call(checksumMethod,e1,e1);
        var e2=Expression.Lambda<Func<Int32>>(checksumExpression);
        int outChecksum = SqlFunctions.ChecksumAggregate(query.Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)e2));
```

But can't quite make it passed runtime.  I get a Nullable'1 Int32 can't be cast into an Int32.  Sounds like it should.

EDIT 2:

Although this doesn't answer my original question I found a hack around it.

```
    public int calculateChecksum<T, TContext>(DbContext context, IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, DateTime? TimeStamp, int Offset = 1)
    {
        if (TimeStamp == null) {TimeStamp = new DateTime(1800,1,1);}
        string filterExp = sortColumn + " = @0";
        query = query.Where<T>(filterExp, TimeStamp);
        query = query.OrderBy<T>(sortColumn);
        query = query.Take(Offset);

        string sql = query.ToString();
        sql = string.Format("select checksum_agg(BC) from ( select binary_checksum(*) as BC from ({0}) b ) c",sql);
        int result = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
```

I need a beer!

Comment: Are you pursuing the checksum to verify data integrity... Or just to create a unique id?  If it's the later, can you add a guid column?

Comment: @Jared Dykstra - To verify data integrity